# Responsive one line text and inputbox

Tags: css, responsive-design

What is the best/correct way of making a `table` like thing with `divs`.

I've tried different methods, with `position:` and using percentage's.

What I want is text and `input` box on the same line and make the `input` box scale with the size of the parent `div`, responsive design.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ok7gvo9v/)

Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I dont think using Percentage's is a good way of doing this.. so i really have no clue how i can get it to work better without using it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ok7gvo9v/ Here is the JSFIddle link, it didnt work in the thread.. it seems like.

Comment: have you tried: #box input[type="text"]{width: inherit}

Comment: @CodeRomeos `width: inherit` will inherit `90%` `width` and not `100%` of `strip-right`

Comment: Please try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/ok7gvo9v/28/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this extra line of CSS -

```
#box input[type="text"]
{
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* This line */
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ok7gvo9v/5/)

You can also use - `display: table-cell` on `div` to mimick like a `table cell`, similarly, you have `display: table-row`, `table-column`, etc. They implement table like behavior to divs.